# push notification to client when Firebase have a new child doesn't work

Tags: push-notification, socket.io, firebase

The code below is listening to new child added to Firebase then push it to client using socket.io, the problem that the socket.io doesn't fire the emit, any idea of how to make it send the data to the client?

Server:

```
FirebaseRef.endAt().limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
console.log('new GPS point added ' + childSnapshot.val());

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('new GPS point added 2' + childSnapshot.val());
    socket.volatile.emit('GpsPoint', childSnapshot.val());

    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
}); });
```

Client: (inside angular Control)

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
    socket.on('GpsPoint', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The socket connection should be done outside the Firebase function:

```
var sockets=[];
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('New socket: '+ socket);
sockets.push(socket);});
```

Inside the Firebase function we should use the sockets that already connected to an client :

```
FirebaseRef.endAt().limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function (childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
  for(var i=0;i<sockets.length;++i) {
      console.log('Socket'+sockets[i]);
      socket=sockets[i];
      socket.volatile.emit('GpsPoint', childSnapshot.val());
}});
```